# Problem when trying to render a HTML page using Node and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to render a HTML document by using express. The code that I'm doing below:

```
import { URL } from 'url'

const __dirname = decodeURI(new URL('.', import.meta.url)) 

import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const port = 3000

import { join } from 'path'

const basePath = join(__dirname, 'templates')

//testing the output
console.log('__dirname:', __dirname)
console.log('basePath:',basePath)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  // res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/index.html`)
  // res.sendFile(`${basePath}/index.html`)
  // res.sendFile('index.html',{root:basePath})
  res.send(__dirname + '/templates/index.html');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running in port:${port}`)
})
```

I was expecting to get the content of this HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Home Express!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the response that I'm getting is:
[This image shows my localhoost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MyeL.jpg)

I've tried to use the commented lines (into the app.get) : But the one that gave me a better result were the one that's not commented. Finally I don't know what I'm doing wrong in this case.

PS: It's my first post here, suggestions to ask in a better way are really welcome too.

**Edit 1** - Maybe this image can help finding the error: [Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFzWs.png)

**Edit 2** - Print of my screen with the code and the error

As the comment that i did: "I did what you've said, i whote the line:
`res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'templates','index.html'));`

But in summary I've tried to use: `res.send(join(__dirname, 'templates', 'index.html'));` to see what output would come of this line, and I've got:

file:\D:\Curso_Node\6_EXPRESS\3_render_html\templates\index.html

The problem when I use:

`res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'templates','index.html'));`

Is that I end up getting the following message: TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile"

The issue might be summarized as:

I don't know what is wrong with the files or the path name.

**Edit 3 - We got a FUNCTIONAL SOLUCTION:**

```
import { URL } from 'url'

const __dirname = decodeURI(new URL('.', import.meta.url)) 

import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const port = 3000

import { join } from 'path'

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(join(process.cwd(), 'templates', 'index.html'))
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`App running in port:${port}`)
})
```

The HTML remains the same as above. [The code and the Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX90h.jpg)

Comment: In this case you're sending a string (the filename), which is what is displayed.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure? you should use sendFile with the correct file path

Comment: @Fcmam5 I've put a print of my folder structure. I'm having trouble when it comes to put the right file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're constructing the path to the file you want to send over using `__dirname` from `const __dirname = decodeURI(new URL('.', import.meta.url))`

This suggests that you are constructing a web URL, as opposed to a local file path.

`sendFile` expects a filepath so you'll probably want something more like this:

`sendFile(join(process.cwd(), 'templates', 'index.html'))`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It worked as I was expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You have [`res.send()`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.send)

```
res.send(__dirname + '/templates/index.html');
```

Which is sending the file path as a string, as you could return

```
res.send('Any string');
```

And have it displayed your responses.

If you want to return the file, you should use [`res.sendFile`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.sendFile) which is supported since Express v4.8.0

```
res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'templates','index.html'));
```

Or:

```
const basePath = join(__dirname, 'templates')
...
res.sendFile(join(basePath, 'index.html'));
```

Or

```
res.sendFile('index.html', { root: join(__dirname, 'templates') });
```

Why using `path.join()`:

In the documentation or the tutorial you followed, they might be using a Linux or macOS machine so the paths of files are constructed with slashes (`/`) e.g `/path/to/file`. But for windows this is done with backslashes (`\`) `D:\path\to\file` to avoid any issues constructing these paths we use Node.js's [`path.join`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) method to do this for us

Comment: I did what you've said, i whote the line: 

res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'templates','index.html'));

I will answer my question below to show the results that I'm getting: But in summary I've tried to use:

res.send(join(__dirname, 'templates', 'index.html'));

The output of this line was: 

file:\D:\Curso_Node\6_EXPRESS\3_render_html\templates\index.html

But the problem when I use:

res.sendFile(join(__dirname, 'templates','index.html'));

I end up getting the following message:

TypeError: path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile

Comment: Please check my edit, try with `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'templates') });`

Comment: @Gi_Developer it looks like you're providing `sendFile` with a URL rather than a file path, is that possible? Basically, I think the problem is the `file:\` part. See my answer…

Comment: @Fcmam5 I've tried to use the line that you updated here: `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'templates') });`, but I don't know why, it still getting an error: ReferenceError: path is not defined.